# Having troubles with unity camera depth texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a shader that makes things darker the further from the camera  they are,the way it works underwater, but when I try to work with the camera depth ,I get "error CS0103: The name 'depthTextureMode' does not exist in the current context".

This is the code I tried to run

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;    

[ExecuteInEditMode,ImageEffectAllowedInSceneView]
    public class FogEffect : MonoBehaviour
    {   public Material _mat;
    
    
        void Start()
        {
            GetComponent<Camera>().depthTextureMode = depthTextureMode.Depth;
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            
        }
        private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
        {
            Graphics.Blit(source,destination,_mat);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[DepthTextureMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DepthTextureMode.html) is an enum and the first letter needs to be uppercase.

This compiled and run without issues on my machine.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FogEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.Depth;
    }
}
```